# redux-observable - action$.ofType is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-observable

I'm trying to do a small POC of using redux-observable so bear with me, all of my code is in one file (index.js)

I'm getting this error:

> action$.ofType is not a function

at the marked line of code below:

**index.js**

```
//@flow
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import Vepo from './components/vepo/Vepo'
import keywords from './components/keywords/keywords.reducer'
import categories from './components/categories/categories.reducer'
import initialState from './config/config'
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'remote-redux-devtools'
import React from 'react'
import devToolsEnhancer from 'remote-redux-devtools'
import Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'

import { ajax } from 'rxjs/observable/dom/ajax'
import { createEpicMiddleware } from 'redux-observable'
import {  } from 'redux-observable'

const FETCH_CATEGORIES = 'FETCH_CATEGORIES'
const FETCH_CATEGORIES_FULFILLED = 'FETCH_CATEGORIES_FULFILLED'

// action creators
const fetchCategories = Categories => ({ type: FETCH_CATEGORIES, payload: Categories });
const fetchCategoriesFulfilled = payload => ({ type: FETCH_CATEGORIES_FULFILLED, payload });

// epic
const fetchCategoriesEpic = action$ =>
  action$.ofType(FETCH_CATEGORIES)<=======================THIS LINE
    .mergeMap(() =>
      ajax.getJSON(`https://localhost:4000/categories`)
        .map(response => fetchCategoriesFulfilled(response))
    );


const categories1 = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_CATEGORIES_FULFILLED:
      return [action.payload.login]
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const reducer = combineReducers(
  {
    searchForm: combineReducers(
    { 
      keywords, 
      categories 
    })
  }
)
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  applyMiddleware(fetchCategoriesEpic)
  //composeWithDevTools(createEpicMiddleware(fetchCategoriesEpic))
)

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Vepo />
  </Provider>
)

export default App
```

The error makes it sound like I have not imported redux-observable correctly. I use webpack 2. I have done `yarn add redux-observable` which is all that is required then I can just do `import xxx` but am I importing correctly in my code above? I am unsure how to import redux-observable. I cannot see it being done in the docs.

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "vepo",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
            "./app/fonts"
        ]
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "moduleNameMapper": {
            "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
            "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "flow-typed": "^2.0.0",
        "immutable": "^3.8.1",
        "native-base": "^2.1.0",
        "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
        "react-native": "^0.43.3",
        "react-native-multiple-choice": "^0.0.8",
        "react-native-select-multiple": "^1.0.3",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
        "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
        "redux": "^3.6.0",
        "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
        "redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
        "reselect": "^3.0.0",
        "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
        "yoga": "^0.0.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
        "babel-jest": "19.0.0",
        "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
        "eslint": "^3.17.0",
        "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.3",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx": "^0.0.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.3.1",
        "flow-bin": "^0.42.0",
        "jest": "19.0.2",
        "jest-cli": "^19.0.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
        "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
        "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am unsure how to import redux-observable. I cannot see it being done in the docs.

Setting up redux-observable is described here in the docs: https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/basics/SettingUpTheMiddleware.html However it appears you have indeed seen that, cause you are importing it.

You're *almost* correct in how you set it up, and in fact you have commented out code that does it correctly.

```
applyMiddleware(fetchCategoriesEpic)
//composeWithDevTools(createEpicMiddleware(fetchCategoriesEpic))
```

You're accidentally passing the Epic as-is, to `applyMiddleware` instead of passing it as an argument to `createEpicMiddleware`

```
applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(fetchCategoriesEpic))
```

That should solve it!

Comment: Thank you! It does work. However I would like to use `remote-redux-devtools` (so use my commented out line instead) but it has an error "store.getState is not a function". I was wondering if my code must be wrong somewhere else in my app. But it's working when I use `applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(fetchCategoriesEpic))`. Do you have any idea what it could be that makes it have that error only when using `composeWithDevTools(createEpicMiddleware(fetchCategoriesEpic))`?

Comment: `composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(createEpicMiddleware(fetchCategoriesEpic)))` did the trick. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

According to me if you are using yarn then to add a single package you have to use `yarn add your-package-name` and what you did is `yarn install redux-observable` please change this to `yarn add redux-observable`

When we use `yarn install` ? `yarn install` is used when you have already defined your package names in `package.json` and running just `yarn install` makes it work and installs all the packages in few seconds.

Cheers :)

Comment: Ah man you're right sorry I did use `add`. I said it wrong in my question. Apologies.